# Enhance the degree of parallelization of groupReduce transformation

Tags: java, apache-flink

In my Flink program I transform my data using a `flatMap` operation which divides several blocks of data in multiple smaller blocks. These blocks have a "position" attribute which describes their position in the respective original block. Now I use a `groupReduce` which needs to transform all small blocks which share the same "position" attribute. So it should be easily distributable on multiple nodes. But when I run my program on multiple nodes the `groupReduce` is executed with a dop of 1.

I guess this is because I have only one `DataSet`, but it seems that a `GroupedDataSet` is not available in Flink Java API. Is there another possibility to enhance the dop of my `groupReduce` transformation?

Here is the code I am using (dummy code ignoring "details"):

```
DataSet<SlicedTile> slicedTiles = tiles.flatMap()
    .groupBy(position)
    .sortGroup(time)
    .getDataSet()
    //Until here the dop is correct

DataSet<SlicedTile> processedSlicedTiles = slicedTiles.reduceGroup;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is the `getDataSet()` call. It returns the *input* of the grouping operation. Hence, the dataset represented by `slicedTiles` is neither grouped nor are its groups sorted but instead it is the result of the `flatMap` transformation and the `groupBy` and `sortGroup` calls are not considered in the program at all.

Applying a `groupReduce` (or `reduce`) operation on a non-grouped dataset is always a non-parallel operation because all elements of the input data set are processed as a single group.

Logically, the three transformation `groupBy().sortGroup().reduceGroup()` belong together and are translated into a single `groupReduce` operator (maybe with an additional combiner if the `GroupReduceFunction` is combinable).

If you change your implementation as follows, it should work as expected.

```
DataSet<SlicedTile> slicedTiles = tiles.flatMap()
    .groupBy(position)
    .sortGroup(time)
    .reduceGroup(yourFunction);
```

I will open a JIRA issue to add JavaDocs to the `Grouping.getDataSet()` method to document the behavior of this function.